# Why is $\frac{x^n}{x^3+x^4}\chi_{[0,1[} \in \mathcal{L}^1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, continuity

In one of our exams it was written without explanation that $f_{n}(x):=\frac{x^n}{x^3+x^4}\chi_{[0,1[} \in \mathcal{L}^1$

But I fail to see how this does not warrant an explanation.

**My ideas**

$\frac{x^n}{x^3+x^4}$ is continuous on $]0,1[$, $\forall n \in \mathbb N$.

I basically want to find a function $g \in \mathcal{L}^1$ such that $f_{n} \leq g, \forall n \in \mathbb N$

on $]0,1[$ this is not difficult as $\frac{x^n}{x^3+x^4}\chi_{]0,1[}\leq\frac{1}{x^3+x^4}$

But what about at $x = 0$, I mean $f_{n}(0)$ is not defined so how can I create a plausible inequality? I do realize that $\{0\}$ has measure zero but how do I successfuly incorporate that into proving that $f_{n} \in \mathcal{L}^1$

Comment: Is $n \in \mathbb{N}$? Because it's not really integrable for $n=0,1,2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the goal is to study the convergence in $\mathcal L^1$ of the sequence $\left(f_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$  hence the fact that $f_n$ is not integrable for $n\in\{0;1;2\}$ is not a problem.

For $n\geqslant 3$ and $x\in(0,1)$,
$$
0\leqslant \frac{x^3}{x^3+x^4}\leqslant \frac{x^3+x^4}{x^3+x^4}=1
$$
hence 
$$
0\leqslant f_n(x)\leqslant x^{n-3}\leqslant 1
$$
and a bounded function on $(0,1)$ is integrable.

Comment: The fact that $n \geq 3 $ is relevant is because $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}f_{n}(x) = 0 $ when $n \geq 3$ correct ? So indeed then $f_{n}$ is defined on $[0,1)$ and we can use $f_{n}\leq 1$ on $[0,1)$ while $n \geq 3$ correct??

Comment: Actually we do not need to define $f_n(0)$; the point is that $\int_0^1 1/t dt$ and $\int_0^1 1/t^2 dt$ are infinite.

Comment: Ok let me ask it plainly, does $f_{n} \chi_{]0,1[} \in \mathcal{L}^1$ imply that $f_{n} \chi_{[0,1[}\in \mathcal{L}^1$ because $\{0\}$ is of measure zero?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$